# How to decrypt with using crpyt_keeper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, decode, decoder

I am fairly new developer given the project which is quite old

My client has requested me to fetch all Candidates on the basis of SSn and EIN, which gets stored in my candidates table under the column of ssn_or_ein.

The issue I am facing is the presence of a gem `crypt_keeper`

`c_unknown = Candidate.where("ssn_or_ein like ?", "%______________________==_______________________==%")`

gives me

```
  `ryVhq2CJJabH2UN561Fmjg==$i2tsOrQXJvFXH7NfnSBs8w==
   SJXcsjQPFueZ+4emIV0csg==$U+pH+4/vNGJvZYg5a3tFhw==
   CzMR0CPHbYWEa5qqKdCoqg==$s+Vm7y5Ls89Hsxm5del0uw==
   TlMZ/1EekzwlA+jSktIRSg==$b/DglTPCO/xJZxHmOJhUxQ==
   Z3KvfSQPPILEAd8r7e1Ixg==$/0hnsgzjBRvWawNBKp61EA==
   wRfCQWUH7/3IXlqkAuoouw==$eMLRIUZTd4et8vaOylYYMw==`
```

How do I decrypt these fields in a rails c query?

Thanks in advance

`gem version gem 'crypt_keeper', '~> 2.2.0'`

Comment: Docs: https://github.com/jmazzi/crypt_keeper#cryptkeeper

Comment: Be advised for 2022: Rails 7 will add encryption to ActiveRecord, obviating gems like cryptkeeper (https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_encryption.html)

Comment: Hi Jared, appreciate the insight. However, am not sure how to use this Gem to get back the actual values entered. The documentation seems limited and I am shooting in the dark.  Can you please guide me on how to use it to decode `ryVhq2CJJabH2UN561Fmjg==$i2tsOrQXJvFXH7NfnSBs8w==`